# How to Create Multi Auth in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have made multi auth but i have problem with final code. I have code like this

```
php artisan make:auth
```

it will generate basic login/register route, view and controller for user table.

Make a admin table as users table for simplicity.

Controller For Admin
app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/AuthController
app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/PasswordController
(note: I just copied these files from app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController here)

config/auth.php

```
//Authenticating guards
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],  

//User Providers
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],  

//Resetting Password  
'passwords' => [
    'clients' => [
        'provider' => 'client',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

});
```

AdminAuth/AuthController.php

Add two methods and specify $redirectTo and $guard

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
protected $guard = 'admin';
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.register');
}
```

it will help you to open another login form for admin

creating a middleware for admin

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

register middleware in kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
];
use this middleware in AdminController e.g.,
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
   }
public function index(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

**And what does this code mean `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` ? And where must i type that code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**And what does this code mean Auth::guard('admin')->user() ?**

In simple word, **Auth::guard('admin')->user()** is used when you need to get details of logged in user. But, in multi auth system, there can be two logged in users (admin/client). So you need to specify that which user you want to get. So by **guard('admin')**, you tell to get user from admin table.

**Where must i type that code?**

As from answer, you can understand that where must you use it. But still I can explain with example. Suppose there are multiple admins. Each can approve users request (like post/comments etc). So when an admin approve any request, then to insert id of that admin into approved_by column of post, you must use this line.